# JavaScript/jQuery: How do I get an array of all attributes in an XML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Given an XML element in jQuery like so:

```
$('<foo oy="vey" foo="bar" here="is" another="attribute" />')
```

Can I use either jQuery or plain old JavaScript to get an array containing the names of all the attributes in an XML element? I would expect this:

```
['oy','foo','here','another']
```

Comment: A word of caution, jquery does not really support forming XML from a string literal. It will work in firefox and maybe in other browsers, but not IE. See http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery : "A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, *not* XML."

Comment: Oh, I should also mention, there are plugins that will allow you to do this if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [jQuery function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core) isn't really meant to parse XML, it can parse HTML, but it's not really the same.

What about using the browser's XML parser:

```
function parseXML(text) {
  var parser, xmlDoc;

  if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  } else {  // IE
    xmlDoc=  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
  }
  return xmlDoc;
}

// Demo
var doc = parseXML('<foo oy="vey" foo="bar" here="is" another="attribute" />');
var foo = doc.childNodes[0];
for (var i = 0; i < foo.attributes.length; i++) {
  var attr = foo.attributes[i];
  alert(attr.name + " = " + attr.value); 
}
```

Run the above code [here](http://jsbin.com/ezawe).

Answer (score 2):

[This plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes) will help you do that.

You can also do it using plain old javascript using something like that :

```
 var elt = document.getElementsByTagName('id'); 
 for (i=0;i<elt.attributes.length;i++){ 
     //elt.attributes[i].nodeName is what you want, .nodeValue for its value.
 }
```

Comment: I am affraid elt is a `HTMLCollection` - collection of elements that does not have `attributes` property - you have to do inner loop for each element in collection (I posted solution as an aswer)

Answer (score 0):

## A) Single `<Foo>` element

Do you need list of attributes of a **single** element?

... if so - do you really need an **array**?

Simple `$('<foo ... />').get(0).attributes`

...will **give you NamedNodeMap (object) of attributes**

## B) All elements `<Foo>` in the whole (XML) document

@Soufiane Hassou 's answer is showing approach but is missing the inner loop...

Do you need to fetch all possible attribute names of an element (e.g. Product element) inside a **whole XML document**?

```
var yourElements = document.getElementsByTagName('Foo'); //get all <Foo> elements
var listOfAttributeNames = []; //prepare empty array for attribute names
var attributeNameBuffer; //buffer for current attribute name in loop

//Loop all elements
for(var i = 0; i < yourElements.length ; ++i){ 

   //Loop all attributes of a current element
   for( k = 0 ; k < yourElements[i].attributes.length ; ++k ){ 
       //Temporary store current attribute name
       attributeNameBuffer = yourElements[i].attributes[k].name;

       //First, 
       //test if the attribute name does not already exist in our array of names
       if( listOfAttributeNames.indexOf(attributeNameBuffer) == -1 )
         listOfAttributeNames.push( attributeNameBuffer ); //if not, add it
   }

} 
console.log(listOfAttributeNames); //display array of attributes in console
```