# HTML5 acronym tag replacement using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, how would you replace every `<acronym>` tag with `<abbr>`?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this in jQuery, or JavaScript full stop. The correct markup should be written into the HTML document — or even better, keep a glossary of terms in XML or JSON (on server side) and transform instances of the term text nodes in the HTML by wrapping them with abbreviation tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('acronym').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.before('<abbr>' + $this.html() + '</abbr>');
  $this.remove();
});
```

Comment: You'll want to copy any attributes over too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I'd try this, but I offer no warranty.

```
$('acronym').each(function(index)
{
  var old = this;
  var newElement = $("<abbr></abbr>");

  $.each(this.attributes, function(index)
  {
    $(newElement).attr(old.attributes[index].name, old.attributes[index].value);
  });

  $(newElement).html(old.html());

  $(this).after(newElement).remove();
});
```

Good luck, and tell me if it's brokeded. If it's brokeded, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You forgot to copy the contents of the original tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). I am assuming you are only using the title attribute.

```
$("acronym").each(function(){//for each acronym element
       var abbr = $("<abbr></abbr>");//create a new abbr element
       var title = $(this).attr("title");//get the title attribute from the acronym element
       abbr.attr("title",title);//add it to the new abbr element
       abbr.html($(this).html());//add in the content of the acronym element
       $(this).replaceWith(abbr);//replace the old with the new!
    });
```

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/EhX2D/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
$('acronym').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<abbr></abbr>').html($(this).html()));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7H4G6/1/

Edit: You'll want to copy attributes too if you have any... Took for granted that you don't.

- Christian

Answer (score 1):

```
$('acronym').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<abbr>' + $(this).html() + '</abbr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("acronym").each(function(idx,HTML) {
  $(this).replaceWith('<abbr title="'+this.title+'">'+HTML+'</abbr>');
});
```