# jQuery get attributes and values of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have this HTML code:

```
    <img id="idgoeshere" src="srcgoeshere" otherproperty="value" />
```

I can reference the element by its id: `$('#idgoeshere'))` Now, I want to get all the properties and their values on that element:

```
src=srcgoeshere
otherproperty=value
```

Is there some way I can do that programmatically using jQuery and/or plain Javascript?

Comment: Please be aware that a property of an element is not the same thing as an attribute of an element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a listing by inspecting the attributes property:

```
var attributes = document.getElementById('idgoeshere').attributes;
// OR
var attributes = $('#idgoeshere')[0].attributes;
alert(attributes[0].name);
alert(attributes[0].value);

$(attributes).each(function()
{
    // Loop over each attribute
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

$('idgoeshere').attr('otherproperty')

For more information - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I think he wants to list all attributes, not some concrete one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

Jquery:

```
var src = $('#idgoeshere').attr('src');
var otherproperty = $('#idgoeshere').attr('otherproperty');
```

Javascript:

```
var src = document.getElementById('idgoeshere').getAttribute('src');
var otherproperty = document.getElementById('idgoeshere').getAttribute('otherproperty');
```

Comment: you can also set the properties:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` for that:

For eg.

```
var mySrc = $('#idgoeshere').attr("src");
var otherProp = $('#idgoeshere').attr("otherproperty");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get a list of all the attributes, see the answers to this question: [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var element = $("#idgoeshere");
$(element[0].attributes).each(function() {
console.log(this.nodeName+':'+this.nodeValue);});
```