# Searching in html on the behalf of ID

Tags: html, search

Is searching possible in html tags on the behalf of ID? for example to find div tag having id="abc".

I can use document.getElementByID("abc"). But i need parent div + its inner HTML in return of searching. i.e if this div has childs

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Be more specific in your question if you expect a specific answer.  Are we to guess what you are using to parse this HTML?

Comment: Yeah, you've said that.  Search with what?  Simply repeating yourself doesn't add more context.

Comment: Ctrl+F in the page source? Not sure what you mean by search.

Comment: I can use document.getElementByID("abc"). But i need HTML in return  of searching.And also if this div has childs

Comment: So you want to use JavaScript to get the HTML of an element with that ID?

Comment: @BoltClock yes I need HTML.

Comment: Just to clarify: given the element `<div id="abc">Some content</div>` you want to get that *exact* HTML, using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by HTML by the ID ? Please clarify.

Comment: Whether you need entire page or out side of the div or inside of the div.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes i need exact html including div having id="abc",the outermost.

Comment: @JDeveloper i need html inside the div including that div

Comment: Ok then my below posted answer is working fine try.

Comment: @JDeveloper that cide is showing inner html and parent div with id="abc" but not showing other attributes ie style attribute of outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you want to achieve:

```
document.getElementById("abc").parentNode.innerHTML; 
//will return <div id="abc"> and other items from parrent

document.getElementById("abc").getAttribute("name");
//will atribute of <div id="abc">

if (document.getElementById("abc").hasChildNodes()) {
    // It has at least one
}
```

Using jQuery is much simplier, you could do that:

```
$("#abc").attr('id') //retunrs id
$("#abc").attr('class') //returns classes
//or other manipulations
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
<script >
function showHTML(){



   var vinner=document.getElementByID("abc").innerHTML;
   var totalinner="<div >"+vinner+"</div>";
   alert(totalinner);

}
</script>
```

HTML part:-

```
<body onload="showHTML();">

<div id="abc">
    Hello inside abc
    <div> 
            Inner div inside abc tag.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Its working fine. You can  [get Attributes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745175/get-the-list-of-attributes-of-a-html-string-using-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for response. But this code will skip other attributes of that outermost div, if it has

Comment: This will only show all attributes and tags inside the abc div.

Comment: Just use var vinner=document.getElementById("abc").outerHTML;   alert(vinner); It should get you the complete DIV

Comment: You may be right @Arun. But what is expecting- inner or outer.

Comment: @JDeveloper I think he wants the entire div element whose Id he possesses . So Outer would be appropriate

Comment: Exactly my above posted answer will show all div inside the ID he is looking.

Comment: @JDeveloper But this code will not show the attributes of div having id="abc" otherthen id.

Comment: And all the *other* attributes and properties that the element might have..?

Comment: this code gives inner + parent           document.getElementById("abc").parentNode.innerHTML;

Comment: your answer helped me but solution i need is answer of Igor S 's solution. Upvote for help :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `outerHTML`, which:

> gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="abc" data-attr="A custom data-* attribute">Some text in the div.</div>
```

The following JavaScript will log, in the console, the HTML of the element of `id` equal to `abc`:

```
var htmlString = document.getElementById('abc').outerHTML;
console.log(htmlString);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8r89X/).

References:

- [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.outerHTML).
- [`outerHTML` compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05).