# jQuery .data() not retrieving data-*

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm testing with IE8.  I just upgraded jQuery from v1.5.2 to v1.6.1 and now the data method isn't working.

the row look like this:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content alt" nodeIndex="2" data-DocAttributeFieldType="TextBox" data-DocClassAttributeFieldId="60777" jQuery16106588245076914028="66">
```

this works:

```
$("#docClassAttributeFields tbody tr:first").attr("data-DocClassAttributeFieldId");
```

this does not work:

```
$("#docClassAttributeFields tbody tr:first").data("DocClassAttributeFieldId");
```

Is there a bug in it?

Here is an example.  Run it with in 1.5.2 and then 1.6 to see how they act differently...
http://jsfiddle.net/5hbKX/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/) *(I suspect the change mentioned in 1.6 is to blame - have you tried removing the case, look at the lastValue example?)*:

> **HTML 5 data- Attributes**
>
> As of jQuery 1.4.3 [HTML 5 data-
>   attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)
>   will be automatically pulled in to
>   jQuery's data object. The treatment of
>   attributes with embedded dashes was
>   changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to
>   the [W3C HTML5
>   specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).
>
> For example, given the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
> ```
>
> All of the following jQuery code will
>   work.
>
> ```
> $("div").data("role") === "page";
> $("div").data("lastValue") === 43;
> $("div").data("hidden") === true;
> $("div").data("options").name === "John";
> ```
>
> Every attempt is made to convert the
>   string to a JavaScript value (this
>   includes booleans, numbers, objects,
>   arrays, and null) otherwise it is left
>   as a string. To retrieve the value's
>   attribute as a string without any
>   attempt to convert it, use the attr()
>   method. When the data attribute is an
>   object (starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[') then
>   jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the
>   string; it must follow valid JSON
>   syntax including quoted property
>   names. The data- attributes are pulled
>   in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer
>   accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

**From the above [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):**

> A **custom data attribute** is an
>   attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at
>   least one character after the hyphen,
>   is XML-compatible, and contains no
>   characters in the range U+0041 to
>   U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to
>   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).
>
> **All attributes on HTML elements in
>   HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased
>   automatically, so the restriction on
>   ASCII uppercase letters doesn't affect
>   such documents.**

Comment: I guess that's it.  Changing to lowercase fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/5hbKX/1/ That kind-of stinks, this is much less readable: .data("docclassattributefieldid") vs .data("DocClassAttributeFieldId")

Comment: Interesting side note, if you view the source in Firebug (FF) and Firebug-lite (IE) the data-* is lowercased, but viewing it in IE Developer Tools it is mixed case.

Comment: If captial letters are not allowed, use-hyphens-to-concatenate-words-instead.

Comment: Ok, that adds to the confusion a little, capital letters work if there is a hyphen.  So .data("id-D") works, .data("idB") does not...  http://jsfiddle.net/5hbKX/2/

Comment: Now I see...  _3. For each name on the list, for each U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) in the name that is followed by a character in the range U+0061 to U+007A (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN SMALL LETTER Z), remove the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) and replace the character that followed it by the same character **converted to ASCII uppercase**._

Comment: @Homer, if you put your values in to the HTML hyphenated, then you can pull them out camel-case if you wish.  It is a bit annoying breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, just glad it was an easy fix.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get them with the hyphens intact?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: You can retrieve the full attribute set easily enough, which preserves the hyphenation as far as I can tell playing in Chrome. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16935800/438971) - Then you could easily filter through for entries starting with `'data-'`.

Comment: @Orbling thats exactly what I ended up doing. The standardized _inconsistencies_ are sometimes inconvenient and weird because they attempt to support legacy methods.

Comment: "this is much less readable: .data("docclassattributefieldid") vs .data("DocClassAttributeFieldId")". 

How about .data("docClassAttributeFieldId")?