# jQuery class selector - accessing attributes on selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a page that has multiple elements with the class "chained". I want to use a class selector so that I can select all of these, and run some additional code based on some data attributes (which will be different for each element). My code so far is:

```
$('.chained_child').remoteChainedTo('chained_parent'
   + $(this).data('chained-parent'), $(this).data('chained-url'));
```

I believe the problem is with this part: `$(this).data('chained-parent')` - this does not appear to be working. How can I select the data attribute of the selected element?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$(this).data('chained-parent')`?

Comment: As above - $(this) has no context where you've put it

Comment: This might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/a/6510009/896341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over the matched set of elements and run a function for each one:

```
$('.chained_child').each(function () {
    $(this).remoteChainedTo('chained_parent' + $(this).data('chained-parent'), $(this).data('chained-url'));
});
```

As you can see in the above code, inside the `.each()` callback `this` refers to the current underlying DOM node (not a jQuery object, hence the need to pass it to jQuery).

Note that some jQuery methods will accept a function as a single argument, which will be called once for each element in the matched set in an implicit `.each()` loop. Looking at the source of the plugin you're using shows that that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use like this

```
$(".chained").each(function(){
//add data as you want
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(this).attr('data-chained-parent')
```

OR

```
$(this).data('chainedParent')
```