# How to get the data object from a tag in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

In chrome, this line of code returns something useful.

```
$('[data-buyername]').data()
```

obviously, it will return the value of the tag `data-buyername='somethingArbitrary'`

In IE8 though, `.data()` doesn't return anything.

Does anyone know how to get the data (both key and value) from a tag like this?

...

In chrome, .data() returns a dictionary {'buyername':'somethingArbitrary'}, but IE8 returns an empty dictionary {}

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509841/jquery-data-not-retrieving-data

Comment: When you call `.data()` with no parameters, you get an **object** back, not a string.  To get the "data-buyername" value from an element as a string you have to use `.data("buyername")`

Comment: Im ok with getting back a dictionary rather than a string, but IE8 isn't even doing that.

Also, all of the keys I'm using are arbitrary, so I need the call to return the key and value, and therefore have to use .data() instead of .data('key')

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specifically try this in IE8 but you could see if manually looking through the `element's` attributes works:

```
var buyerData = $('[data-buyername]').get(0); // Returns the vanilla DOM element

function getData(el) {
    var o = {},
        attrs = el.attributes,
        attr = null;

    for (var i in attrs) {
        attr = attrs[i];
        if (attr.name && attr.name.indexOf('data-') != -1) o[attr.name] = attr.value;
    }

    return o;
}

var data = getData(buyerData);
console.log(data);
```