# Parse $.extend configuration from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I know I can use $.data but how can I iterate trough all `data-` attributes and merge the values with the default plugin configuration?

```
(function($){

  $.fn.plugin = function(opts){  

    opts = $.extend({
      foo: 'abc',
      boo: 45
    }, opts);

    return this.each(function(){        
          ...
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

So if I use

`$('.el').plugin();`

it should look for data attributes on `.el`, like data-foo etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method supports data- attributes.

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with
>   embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5
>   specification.

Calling it without speciying a parameter will return an object with key/values pairs for all the data attributes:

```
var mydata = $("#mydiv").data();
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `each()` loop, you can merge the object returned by [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) with your defaults, then merge the `opts` argument with the result in a single call to [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.fn.plugin = function(opts) {
    return this.each(function() {        
        var thisOpts = $.extend({
            foo: "abc",
            boo: 45
        }, $(this).data(), opts);
        // Now use 'thisOpts' as operating parameters for this element...
    });
};
```

This should achieve what you want: the `opts` argument has the highest priority, followed by the `data-` attributes of the current element, followed by the plugin defaults.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the attributes for an element like this:

```
//get the element and setup an array for output
var el  = document.getElementById("o"),
    arr = [];

//loop through each attribute for the element
for (var i = 0, attrs = el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i < l; i++){

    //if the current attribute starts with `data-` then add it to the array
    if (attrs.item(i).nodeName.substr(0, 5) == 'data-') {
        arr.push(attrs.item(i).nodeName);
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ksbD3/1/

Also I got most of the above code from this answer: [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data()` method on the jQuery object which will give all the data attributes as key/value pair. Try this.

```
(function($){

  $.fn.plugin = function(opts){  

    //this.data() will give { foo: 'abc', boo: 45 ... }
    opts = $.extend(this.data(), opts);

    return this.each(function(){        
          ...
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

`.data()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers that pointing out using  opts = $.extend(this.data(), opts);

One important fact need to be added here: is the transformation of HTML data-attribute.

data-cool**N**ame can be accessed like this this.data(cool**n**ame)

data-another-**c**ool-**n**ame can be accessed like this this.data(another**C**ool**N**ame)

Details: [Does jQuery internally convert HTML5 data attribute keys to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985204/does-jquery-internally-convert-html5-data-attribute-keys-to-lowercase)

Case sensitive of java and the transformation of the attribute name might be a pitfall if you don't know about.