# Retrieving HTML data-attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get the values stored in the data attributes using jQuery ?

```
<div class="sm-tot" data-ts-speed="500" data-ts-interval="4000" data-ts-newVal="5000" >
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the expected result? What was the actual result? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Morais, you should check Alytrem's answer as correct.

Answer (score 157):

Use the jQuery [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
var speed = $("yourdiv").data("ts-speed");
```

Comment: this from jQuery 1.4.3 - on one project i have 1.4.2 =)

Comment: this one doesn't work for me. The answer below, use `attr` instead of `data` works for me.

Comment: @Morais last seen May 18, 2016 and still no check for the right answer.

Comment: Maybe it didn't work for @Carrie because of older version. It works perfectly with jQuery 3.2.1.

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to use the .attr function:

```
var speed = $("yourdiv").attr("data-ts-speed");
```

Answer (score 11):

[this shoud give you a idea how](http://jsfiddle.net/BLa6X/)

html:

```
<div class="sm-tot" data-ts-speed="500" data-ts-interval="4000" data-ts-newVal="5000" > </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var speed = $("div.sm-tot").data("ts-speed");
    var interval = $("div.sm-tot").data("ts-interval");
    $("div.sm-tot").append("speed: " + speed + "<br />");
    $("div.sm-tot").append("interval: " + interval + "<br />");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="sm-tot" data-ts-speed="500" data-ts-interval="4000" data-ts-newVal="5000" >
```

well, for this div u can get someone attr with jquery using code like this
first follow this pattern

```
   if is Class $(".ClassName").attr('AttrName');
   if is Id  $('#IDname').attr('attrName')
```

if u wan get "data-ts-interval" u will use $('.sm-tot').attr("data-ts-interval");

Answer (score 0):

For getting data attributes using JQuery, you can make use of the attributes function (`.attr()`) and get the value of the required data attribute

```js
let value = $(".sm-tot").attr("data-ts-speed"); // here you have the attr() method which gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

console.log(value); // here is the logged value of your class element
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sm-tot" data-ts-speed="500" data-ts-interval="4000" data-ts-newVal="5000" >
```