# How to get the name of a custom attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an attribute which might look like this `abcjQuery12345`, these  numbers are just an example.
Is there a way to determine an attribute which contains a substring in jQuery?

E.g. `abcjQuery12344353452343452345="12"`

The only thing I know is that the attribute will contain `abc`.

Comment: Firstly, an attribute like that will render your code invalid. Secondly, how do you mean 'contains a substring'? Do you mean it has a value, like `abcjQuery12345="12345"`?

Comment: Include HTML example, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the attributes and check if they contain the string you are looking for. With:

```
​<div customAttr="12" title="me"></div>
<div anotherAttr="Bear"></div>
<div yetAnotherAttr="Elephant"></div>
```

You could use:

```
var m = /another/i; //will look for 'another' in the attribute name (i-flag for case-insensitive search)

$('div').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(this.attributes,function(){
        if (this.name.match(m)){
            $this.addClass('selected'); //either select the matching element
            $this.text(this.name + ' : ' + this.value); //or use its custom-attribute's value
        }
    });
});​
```

See **[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyYCZ/2/)**

Comment: Thanks this was the closest to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3qKF/3/)

```
<div id="div1" myattr="hello" myAttr12342="hello1">Any text</div>​


el = document.getElementById('div1');
attrs=el.attributes
for (var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++)
{
    attrName = attrs.item(i).nodeName;
    attrValue = attrs.item(i).nodeValue; 
    //alert(attrs.item(i).nodeName);
    if(attrName.indexOf('myattr') != -1)
    {
        alert("Attr Name " + attrName + " Attr Value " + attrValue );
    }        
}
​
```

​

Comment: And what would this look like if my custom attribute is myattr123 and I only know that the attribute can contain myattr?

Comment: I have updated my answer now it can match it custom attributes by matching some string pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
var abcAttr, abcName;

​$.each($("#elementID")​[0].attributes, function(index, item) {
    if (item.nodeName.match(/^abc/)) {
        abcName = item.nodeName;
        abcAttr = item.nodeValue;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JFgng/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var customNum = 12345; // Switch this out as necessary.
var value = $('#element').attr('abcjQuery' + customNum);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e6aKM/).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the number

Comment: If you don't know the number, then it sounds like the number is either irrelevant and shouldn't exist in the attribute name, or is part of the attribute value or some other attribute's value, and should be stored as such.

Comment: Well the number is irrelevant, but the value of the attribute is.

Comment: Or perhaps, if you didn't create the attribute, the number was appended to make it more difficult to access and modify the value. If that's the case, then I would be careful doing just that. There might be a better way to access the value of the attribute through whatever created it's API.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method should do the trick

```
var value = $('#element').attr('abcjQuery' + someCustom);
```

but i suggest you to use **data- attributes**. like this  by using [Jquey.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<div id="div1" data-myattr="abcjQuery12345">Any text</div>​
```

for retriving :

```
var value = $('#div1').data('myattr');
alert(value):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
$('a[@name^="abcjQuery"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question here is your answer;

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRsxM/

```
/*!
 * listAttributes jQuery Plugin v1.1.0
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Michael Riddle
 * Licensed under the MIT
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: Sun Mar 28 05:49:39 2010 -0900
 */
if(jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function(prefix) {
            var list = [];
            $(this).each(function() {
                var attributes = [];
                for(var key in this.attributes) {
                    if(!isNaN(key)) {
                        if(!prefix || this.attributes[key].name.substr(0,prefix.length) == prefix) {
                            attributes.push(this.attributes[key].name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.push(attributes);
            });
            return (list.length > 1 ? list : list[0]);
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input').each(function(){
        var attrs = $(this).listAttributes();
         for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++){
            if(attrs[i].indexOf("abc")>-1) itemProccess($(this));
        }

    });
});


function itemProccess(item){
    console.log(item);
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to get attribute value given a string contained in the attribute name:

```
function getVal(element,name){
   var pattern=new RegExp(name,'i');
   return $.grep($(element)[0].attributes, function(n){
       if (n.name.match(pattern)) return n.nodeValue;
   })[0].nodeValue;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EFYdT/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var myAttr = $("#idOfElement").attr("your_custom_attribute_name");
```