# jQuery get all attributes as string variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I've got some simple html a bit like this

```
<a href="" data-type="" data-id="" data-tags="" id="" class="">balrbalr</a>
```

I'd like to be able to get the full contents of `<a>` as a string.

I know you can use `.html` to get the inner html, however if I use

```
var string = $('a').html();
```

If would return, `balrblabrlabr`

If I do `string = $('a').parent.html();`

I'd get ALL of the `<a>`'s inside the parent.

how would I go about just getting the full html content of itself?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use native javascript `outerHTML` property of DOM elements:

```
var string = $('a')[0].outerHTML;
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GZXpV/)**

> The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML)

---

If you wish to get the outerHTML of multiple elements, you can use jQuery `map` function, like in this example:

```
var str = $('#foo a').map(function() {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZXpV/2/)

Comment: @KrishanuDey. Did you use a browser with a `console`? change `console.log` to `alert`

Comment: @KrishanuDey. So.. why doesn't it work for you?! what happen when you change to `alert`?

Comment: Here is another screenshot when using `alert()`. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/c4j4f.png

Answer (score 0):

Set your element's id to "a" and just use this function

```
    function msg() {
        var attrib="";
        var el =document.getElementById('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++) {
            attrib = attrib + ' ' + el.attributes.item(i).nodeName + ' = "' + el.attributes.item(i).nodeValue + '"';
        }
        alert(attrib);
    }
```

Comment: @VisioN. [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/GZXpV/5/), but in a  very unefficient way.

Comment: Now i'm using a veriable `el` rather than using `document.getElementById('a')` multiple times.

Comment: @gdoron Mmm... I have another approach http://jsfiddle.net/GZXpV/6/. Maybe it is not so flexible... Should I add it as an answer?

Comment: @VisioN. Hell no! You regex the whole body!!! do you know how risky and inefficient it is?

Comment: @KrishanuDey You can better assign `document.getElementById('a').attributes` to a variable.

Comment: @gdoron Yeah! I can invent several more "wonderful" solutions ;)

Comment: @VisioN :it works. but will you explain how? what does this expression mean, `/(<a.+id="a".+a>)/.exec(body);` ?

Comment: @KrishanuDey. it's a regular expression looking for an anchor with the `a` id.

Comment: @KrishanuDey This expression shows almost the same approach as you presented in your answer. It should not be used for such an easy task. `outerHTML` does the job. Nothing else needed.