# Is there a way I can get many attributes of an object all at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
    link = {
        action: $link.attr('data-action') || '',
        dialogType: $link.attr('data-dialogType') || '',
        params: $link.attr('data-params') || '',
        title: $link.attr('title') || '',
        viewURL: $link.attr('data-href') || '',
        entity: $link.attr('data-entity') || '',
        row: $link.attr('data-row')
    };
```

I am just wondering. Is there a more clean way that I can do this or am I stuck with having to get the attributes like this.

Comment: If it wasn't for the inconsistency with `viewURL: $link.attr('data-href')` I would suggest something.

Comment: it is not good to get data using attr function, because if you set data with jquery, data(), it would not be in $.attr()

Answer (score 3):

Lots of functions you can pilfer for this: [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Or, just DRY it up:

```
var link = {};

['action', 'dialogType', 'params', 'title', 'href', 'entity', 'row'].forEach(function(i) {
    link[i] = $link.attr('data-' + i) || $link.attr(i);
});
```

Note that this requires changing viewURL to href. Also requires `forEach` support.

Answer (score 1):

simple use this

```
link=$link.data();
link.title=$link.attr('title');
```

edited as suggested by  Wesley Murch

Comment: not more than setted data :) elsewhere i would to use array and loop

Comment: and what i should see ? check this: http://jsfiddle.net/m6zNs/ manual setted object equalent to one which loaded from dom

Comment: @WesleyMurch: You're probably using Chrome or Safari. That property is always there.

Comment: I see property in both cases :)

Comment: I'll give this my vote, you can just do `link.title = $link.attr('title')` afterwards or something, to get the attributes that aren't `data-`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery `extend()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend) (for everything but `title`):

```
link = $.extend(link, $('a#mylink').data());
link.title = $('a#mylink').attr('title');
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/q4hqR/

Comment: i would suggest to use 
`var $link=$('a#mylink');` to not make JQuery to parse dom each time;

Comment: Maybe it needs cached, maybe it doesn't. I'll leave that to the OP's discretion.