# splitting an html line into separate variables with JS

Tags: javascript, html

In pure javascript (not using JQuery/dojo/etc), what is the best/easiest/quickest way to split a string, such as

```
var tempString = '<span id="35287845" class="smallIcon" title="time clock" style="color:blue;font-size:14px;" contenteditable="false">cookie</span>';
```

into

```
var id = 'id="35287845"';
var class = 'class="smallIcon"';
var title = 'title="time clock"';
var style = 'style="color:blue;font-size:14px;"';
var contenteditable = 'contenteditable="false"';
```

**Things to note:**

- a "space" cannot be used as a proper delimiter, since it may appear in a value, such as title, above (time clock).
- maintaining the double quotes around each variable, such as id="35287845" is important
- the opening/closing span tags can be discarded, as well as the content, which in this case, is "cookie"

Comment: What have you tried? Also, removing [tag:java] tag, this has nothing to do with that

Comment: Haven't you seen the famous "don't regex html" rant(s)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1026459

Comment: `class` is a reserved word and can't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, which is to place the input string as innerhtml into a javascript created dom element and then leverage the attributes array

```
//Input html string
var tempString = '<span id="35287845" class="smallIcon" title="time clock" style="color:blue;font-size:14px;" contenteditable="false">cookie</span>';

//make element to contain html string
var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");

//place html string as innerhtml to temp element
tempDiv.innerHTML = tempString;

//leverage attributes array on element
var attributeArray = tempDiv.firstChild.attributes;

//log results
console.log(attributeArray);
```

Note that you may now do something like

```
var classString = attributeArray.class;
```

or

```
var titleString = attributeArray.title;
```

**Edit**

Here is a function that will do it:

```
function getAttributesFromString(htmlString)
{
 var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
 tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
 return tempDiv.firstChild.attributes;
}
```

Comment: @Christophe - To make use of the attributes array.

Comment: mmm...is it for specific browsers? I just tried on Chrome, not needed.

Comment: @Christophe - The attributes array is present after `innerHTML`? You are correct, editing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get the properties in the span, check this response telling you how to do it.

[Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

also you could get the properties and make the string concatenating the the values with your strings.

(You can fin a explanation in pure javascript there)