# jquery Getting multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get multiple attributes in jQuery

```
 <input type="text" title="hello there" class="maiz"/>


(function() {
  var inputTitle = $("input").attr("title","class");
  console.log(inputTitle[1])//output:undefined
})();
```

I'm new to jQuery

Comment: Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Is it not possible throug attr() method?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get multiple attributes, you just have to call `attr` again:

```
var input = $("input");
var title = input.attr("title");
var cls   = input.attr("class");
```

Your example sets the value "class" to the title attribute.

Or more similar to your original code:

```
var inputTitle = [input.attr("title"), input.attr("class")];
inputTitle[1]; // gives you 'maiz'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
  var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
  if (attrib.specified == true) {
    console.log(attrib.name + " = " + attrib.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.` - according to Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attributes using the attributes property on the element object:

```
var el = document.getElementById("someId");
var attributes = el.attributes; // Here they are
```

In jQuery you can get the Original element with the get() method, like:

```
var el = $("input").get(0);
var attributes = el.attributes; // Here they are
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.maiz').click(function(){
    for(var i = 0;i < this.attributes.length;i++){
        console.log(this.attributes[i]);
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fuVX/)

Answer (score -2):

Jquery selector works pretty much like the CSS selector. 
    `$('selector')` if you want to select all elements if a particular class 
     `$('.class')` if you want to select class and id 
     `$('.class, #id')`
that's basically it. unless you have a specific question