# Select elements which start with "data-"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I select with plan javascript or jQuery every element which has an attribute that starts with "data-"?

I've tried

```
 $("[data-*"])
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: after selecting what u have to do.What you have tried so far.what is your requirement.

Comment: you need to use the attribute selector this way ,http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Please show us your html

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Does not look like a duplicate to me. This question is about matching elements that expose *any* `data-` attribute. This is not addressed in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: That is not a duplicate of this question..

Comment: [This does the job](http://jsfiddle.net/jN2F7/), I will add it as an answer is this question ever gets re-opened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a non-JQuery function that will do what you need:

```
function getAllDataElements() {
    //get all DOM elements
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    //array to store matches
    var matches = [];
    //loop each element
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        //get all attributes for the element and loop them
        var attributes = element.attributes;
        for (var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
            //get the name of the attribute
            var attr = attributes.item(j).nodeName;
            //check if attibute name starts with "data-"
            if (attr.indexOf("data-") == 0) {
                matches.push(element); //add it to matches
            }
        }
    }
    return matches; //return results
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var results = getAllDataElements();

results.forEach(function (i) {
    i.style.color = "#FF0000";
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jN2F7/)