# react not receiving prop from html

Tags: laravel, reactjs

I have a react component in a file named ts.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class Ts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       var expected = {
            lowercase:'Onlylowercase',
            snakeCase:'justSnakeCase',
            ProperCase: 'AndProperCase'
        };
        console.log("expected:",expected);
        console.log("props:",props);
        console.log("this.props",this.props);
        console.log("props.lowercase",props.lowercase);
        this.state={'lowercase':this.props.lowercase};

    };

    render() {
        return NULL;
    }

}
if (document.getElementById('ts')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Ts />, document.getElementById('ts'));
}
```

I also have a html page from where this is called:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My TS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <Ts lowercase="onlylowercase" id="ts" snakeCase="justSnakeCase" ProperCase="AndProperCase">
          </Ts>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My issue is I can't get the values lowercase="onlylowercase" id="ts" snakeCase="justSnakeCase" ProperCase="AndProperCase" recognised as props in the constructor. I need to pass in some stuff from the html to populate the initial state of the component.

When I open the HTML with Chrome console open I get:

```
expected: {lowercase: "Onlylowercase", snakeCase: "justSnakeCase", ProperCase: "AndProperCase"}
props: {}
  __proto__: Object

or it is this.props?: {}
  __proto__: Object

props.lowercase undefined
this.props.lowercase undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I am expecting props to be a javascript object with properties of lowercase, snakeCase and ProperCase, like the var expected.

I don't think I need to use componentWillReceiveProps - as I am trying to follow the pattern describe in the documentation here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor
and pass in props as html attributes as described here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

I have excluded from this post the detail of the node modules and javascript includes - as the Ts component's constructor is being called which demonstrates the Ts class is "there" and my npm config is OK - it is including react and other required modules. The {{ asset() }} function is a Laravel function. The html is part of a blade template in a Laravel app.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: not a react user, console.log on props and this.props its giving you an object. and then you are trying to convert that object to lowercase!

Comment: I am expecting props to be an object containing properties of lowercase, snakeCase and ProperCase. Instead it is an empty object, containing only the prototype stuff that all objects contain. I have updated the post above with your feedback, thanks.

Comment: See my answer for injecting props in a React component here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158247/579890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. React doesn't creat a new html tag like "". You only can use  tag in react component. So the right syntax is in html replace

```
<Ts lowercase="onlylowercase" id="ts" snakeCase="justSnakeCase" ProperCase="AndProperCase">
          </Ts>
```

To `<div id="ts"></div>`
and go add to before

```
<script>
   var lowercase="whatever";
   var snakeCase="snakeCase";
   ...
</script>
```

And change to

```
if (document.getElementById('ts')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Ts lowercase={lowercase} snakeCase={snakeCase} />, document.getElementById('ts'));
}
```

ReactDOM will find a dom with id is "ts" and replace it by your ts component.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Giang Le, but this technique is difficult becuase: My Ts.js file defines the React component, and contains the RectDOM.render function. I use Mix (a wrapper around WebPack) to include Ts.js file into the final 'app.js' file - and I need to re-run my npm script every time is changes. Hence I can't put "run-time" values in that file. If I move the eactDom.render(....) code into a script tag in my HTML file, I get ReactDOM undefined, even if it is AFTER <script src='app.js'> where ReactDOM is defined as a global.

Comment: Yeah. I had a solution for u. In html file (blade tenplate) you define variable lowercase... and in ts conponent you call <Ts lowercase={lowercase}... if you dont understand i will post answer with code later. I just wake up. Good morning :)))

Comment: Good morning to you also! If my <Ts lowercase={lowercase}... is in the js file (not the HTML file) then it will need to be processed by webpack into the app.js file to work - which will not happen in production environment.

Comment: I just updated my answer. If you want change "lowercase", "snakecase" just change in html file. Doen't need run webpack again

Comment: Thanks Giang - your suggestion worked for me. I added a <script> tag into the header var= myVar {{ $myVar }} to define global javascript variables from the php passed from my controller and incuded these in the ReactDOM.render() call (in the blade template, not the component definition js file) as you suggest. This left the Component definition js file static, so did not require re-running webpack every time! Thanks