# Extract property of a tag in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, greasemonkey

Is it possible to extract properties of a `HTML tag` using Javascript.
For example, I want to know the values present inside with the `<div>` which has `align = "center"`.

```
<div align="center">Hello</div>
```

What I know is:

```
var division=document.querySelectorAll("div");
```

but it selects the elements between `<div> & </div>` and not the `properties` inside it.

I want to use this in the **Greasemonkey script** where I can check for some **malicious properties of a tag** in a website using `Javascript`.

Hope I'm clear..!!

Comment: So you want it to select what? "Hello", the div element, or `align="center"`?

Comment: Tag properties are called attributes. What kind of malicious attributes you are looking for?

Comment: I think this is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) function. Which is accessible though the element.

You would use it like this.

```
var division = document.querySelectorAll('div')
for(var i=0,length=division.length;i < length;i++)
{
    var element = division[i];
    var alignData = division.getAttribute('align'); //alignData = center
    if(alignData === 'center')
    {
       console.log('Data Found!');
    }      
}
```

If you're looking to see what attributes are available on the element, these are available though

```
division.attributes
```

[MDN Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes)

So for instance in your example if you wanted to see if an align property was available you could write this.

```
//Test to see if attribute exists on element
if(division.attributes.hasOwnProperty('align'))   
{
    //It does!
}
```

Comment: shouldnt that be `var alignData = division[0].getAttribute('align'); //alignData = center` ?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I was thinking getElementById. Good catch

Comment: +1 for you :D also to note: i figure he may have more divs...creating a for loop with `if(division[i].getAttribute('align') == "center") {//dosomething}` will help to find the ones that have that property.

Comment: Yeah good suggestion.  Side note: Im actually kinda happy not to see jQuery as one of the tags for this question.

Comment: @13ruce1337 
It works for me.. But I got a further problem in nested divs.. (let there be 2, outer and inner)

 Will **document.querySelectorAll('div')** select both divs or only the outer one..??

Comment: @BhavukMathur if you add a selector in the `querySelectorAll()` method it will return a list of elements, that matches the selector, as a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). From there you could make a for loop to do what you need.

Comment: @BhavukMathur I updated the question to show you how to loop on the query

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll('div[align="center"]');
```