# Removing all dynamic 'data attributes' of an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a div where dynamic data- attributes get added on some tags.
(name of data- attributes to be generated dynamically by script, so there is no way my script will know the NAME of data-attribute)

```
<div data-1223="some data" data-209329="some data" data-dog="some value"> </div>
```

Now, I want to write a code in which it resets the div by removing all the data attributes and their values.

I can use

```
$('div').attr('data-209329',"")
```

but the problem is I don't know the name of data-attribute that will be added.
the data-attribute that will be added is dynamic and I don't have control of it.

removing div and reinserting div is not an option.
Pls help.
thanks in advance

Comment: There is a function to remove attribute in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/ it's more clean that ""

Comment: Have you tried using .removeAttr()

Comment: @Pranav I think he wants to remove all `data-` attributes and he don't know all names.

Comment: Take a look at this subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

 There is some functions that allow you to find all the attributes of an html tag. You just have to look at it, find the data-* attribute and remove them by removeAttr()

Comment: @ Epsil0neR he can get all the data attributes using .data().

Comment: @3rror404 the link that you have given is for all data- attributes whose 'name' I m aware of!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

YOu can use like this

```
var data = $("div").data();

var keys = $.map(data, function (value, key) {
    return key;
});
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    $("div").removeAttr("data-" + keys[i]);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/182/)

**Edit**

Suggested by @Mottie

```
$.each($('div').data(), function (i) {
    $("div").removeAttr("data-" + i);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/183/)

Comment: +1 I'm not sure who downvoted, but this method works.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi your solution likes mine but i don't know who downvote solutions...

Comment: You can shorten this to `$.each( $('div').data(), function(i){ $("div").removeAttr("data-" + i); });` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WVfSg/262/))

Comment: @Mottie Thats cool. Didnt think about that initially.

Comment: This works. Thanks!!!
only one issue... its combinining attributes eg if the attribute is data-hello-one its combining the value to helloOne (tried putting a alert for keys[i] in for in loop)

Comment: This does not work, if there are more than one hyphen: http://jsfiddle.net/jr1d4s58/
The problem is that .data() returns camelCase keys.

Comment: This is a working version, but there might by an easier way: http://jsfiddle.net/vgo7fL4y/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code :

```
var data = $('div').data();

for(var i in data){
    //for change 
    $('div').attr("data-"+i,"something");
    //for remove
    $("div").removeAttr("data-" + i);
}
```

The `$('div').data();` prepare a list of all data attributes in `var data` variable.
Then you can work with it.
This is [fiddle of this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/WVfSg/262/).

**UPDATE**
Suggested by @Mottie

```
 $.each($('div').data(), function (i) {
        //for change 
        $('div').attr("data-"+i,"something");
        //for remove
        $("div").removeAttr("data-" + i);
    });
```

Comment: Your code works, but it's not being up-voted as much because you are using a `for...in` loop which [isn't always ideal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the [`removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) function is what you are looking for here. This will remove all `data` information stored on the element.

> The .removeData() method allows us to remove values that were previously set using .data(). When called with the name of a key, .removeData() deletes that particular value; **when called with no arguments, all values are removed.** Removing data from jQuery's internal .data() cache does not affect any HTML5 data- attributes in a document; use .removeAttr() to remove those.

It will not however remove the actual attributes from the elements. In order to remove the actual attributes, you'll need to extract a list of the existing attributes. You could do this by inspecting the `data()` function of an element (before running `removeData`).

The `data()` function will return an object of `key => value` pairs that you can then use to remove the actual attributes from the element using [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).

Comment: The data- attribute is dynamic....so i will not be able to remove it until and unless i have a name of the attribute. SO, removeData() will not work as it accepts NAME of data- attribute to be removed

Comment: @Prashant - yes. And you can extract the values using the `data()` function.