# How to remove angularjs attributes and classes from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS app that renders a parent element containing some nested elements from a template using ng-bind and ng-repeat. I would like to grab the HTML (innerHtml) of the generated element (as a string) for usage in a different application (where it is to be used as static HTML, outside the context of AngularJS).

This is easy enough to do by using `jQuery('#parent-element').html()`. The problem with this approach is that the HTML string contains Angular attributes (for example ng-bind) as well as Angular generated comments (from ng-repeat) and classes (such as ng-scope).

I can probably come up with some regular expression to clean up all of these from the string directly, but I would love to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

So, is there a more "Angular" way to either prevent the attributes/classes/comments from being generated or to extract a clean version of the source HTML of the generated elements?

**UPDATE:**
For @suhas-united and others who might find this useful, I ended up using the following which works well enough for my use case-

```
var cleaner = angular.element('#dirtier')
            .html()
            .replace(/<!--[^>]*-->/gi, '')
            .replace(/\n/g, '')
            .replace(/ng-.+?\b/g, '')
            .replace(/ng-.+?=".*?"/g, '')
            .replace(/class=""/g, '')
            .replace(/\"/g, "\\\"")
            .replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Comment: First of all, you don't parse HTML with regexes. Especially not in JavaScript.
Is this something that has to be done automatically? Since you're  building a new project, why not copy the HTML and just remove the angular code, yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I understand your comment re parsing the HTML. This has to be done automatically. It's not a single time conversion

Comment: did you find a way to this ?

Comment: .replace(/ng-.+?=".*?"/g, '')  this is not working... my ngrepeats are not completely replaced ... ="cat in cats" this part is left behind

Answer (score 1):

need to clear attrs value and then clearing be easy

```
 var x = String(a)
    /*replace comments*/    .replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/gm, "")
    /*replace value of attrs*/    .replace(/="(.*?)"/gm, "")
    /*replace html markup */ .replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "")
    /*replace whitespaces */  .replace(/\s/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a very large number of ng- attributes, you could try something like this:

```
var div = $("#mydiv");
div.removeAttr("ng-repeat").removeAttr("ng-bind")....
```

If you have a large number of them, see [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery) and you could add a method

```
div.removeAllAttr("ng-")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would still have to deal with ng generated classes and comment tags.

Comment: Are you looking for an angular way of removing them? $(...).angular.removeAttr(); ?

Comment: Thanks, but I must be missing something. I mean that angular generates comments, such as "<!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->", which I need to clean up as well

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't think about those. Not sure what you can do about them but like Cerbrus said don't use regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I found a soultion:

```
    var x = angular.element('#id').html()
        .replace(/(ng-\w+-\w+="(.|\n)*?"|ng-\w+="(.|\n)*?"|ng-(\w+-\w+)|ng-(\w+))/g, '')
        .replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/gm, "")
```

It clears any "ng-" directives and "ng-" classes!

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. Problem is that it kills valid classes such foo-ng-bar which are not set by angular and should not be removed. I guess the regex needs to be adjusted to account for the ng- not being in the middle of a word