# How to get all attributes of DOM element?

Tags: javascript

How to copy all user defined attributes for a DOM element into an array? I Unsuccessfully tested to get `["type", "onClick",'value','id']` 
See the following code

Js

```
 var obj=document.getElementById('input')/*.attributes*/,
     array=[],
     index=0;
     for(array[index++] in obj);
 console.log(array);
```

html

```
<input type='button' onClick="Start()" id='input' value="Start"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery Perhaps this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Better Answer

I now recommend [this answer by Tim Kindberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579530/2502532) to the question [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery) that uses `getAttributeNames()` and `getAttribute(name)`, which MDN says "[is a memory-efficient and performant alternative to accessing `Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames)."

---

### Use `Array.from()` or Spread Operator `...`

*Update: `Array.from()` and Spread operator `...` were added to ECMA-262 6th Edition in June 2015, which now has universal modern browser support.*

See [MDN › Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) & [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var elem  = document.getElementById('input'),
    attrs = elem.attributes;

console.log('Array.from(attrs)');
Array.from(attrs).forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    console.log(`    ${name}: ${value}`);
})

console.log('[...attrs]');
[...attrs].forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    console.log(`    ${name}: ${value}`);
})
```

```html
<input type='button' onClick="Start()" id='input' value="Start"/>
```

---

*Note: The following is the legacy answer. It will still work, but the newer `Array.from()` method is now preferred. This could now be considered a polyfill to support pre-ES2015 targets.*

### Use `.slice` to convert the `attributes` property to Array

The `attributes` property of DOM nodes is a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap), which is an Array-like object.

An Array-like object is an object which has a `length` property and whose property names are enumerated, but otherwise has its own methods and does not inherit from [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

[The `slice` method can be used to convert Array-like objects to a new Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like).

```js
var elem  = document.getElementById('input'),
    attrs = elem.attributes;

console.log('Array.prototype.slice.call(attrs)');
Array.prototype.slice.call(attrs).forEach(
    function (cur) {
        console.log(cur.name + ': ' + cur.value);
    }
)
```

```html
<input type='button' onClick="Start()" id='input' value="Start"/>
```

Comment: You can also just call `array = Array.from(obj);`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: That's a great callout. This answer was written in May 2015, but `Array.from()` was not added to [ECMA-262 until the 6th Edition in June 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-array.from). It did not receive wide browser support until later that year — and never was available in IE which was still a concern at the time. I'll update the answer though. It's about time. :)

Answer (score 2):

The attributes are available on the `attributes` `NamedNodeMap`; you access each one with `[]` notation, and there's a `length`.

So:

```js
var array = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementById('input').attributes,
    function(attr) {
        // Use nodeName for the name, nodeValue for the value
        return attr.nodeName;
    });
snippet.log(array.join(", "));
```

```html
<input type='button' onClick="Start()" id='input' value="Start"/>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Using it with your JS, you get:

```
var obj=document.getElementById('input')/*.attributes*/,
     arr=[],
     index=0;

for (var i = 0, atts = obj.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    arr.push(atts[i].nodeName);
}
 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: TypeError: obj is null    

Console Error

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gcatm70/) for me it works fine

Comment: @MohamedBelal put javascript code before the closing body tag