# Take the src of a common class div

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="e1">
<p><img alt="" src="/images/site/pr1.png" /></p>
</div>
<div class="e1">
<p><img alt="" src="/images/site/pr2.png" /></p>

</div>
<div class="e1">
<h1> My new h1 </h1>
</div>
```

How is it possibe to take the content of img src element of the first two div tag which class e1?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("e1")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method on `document`. You can then map the returned [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to an array of `src` attributes.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.e1 img[src]'),
    sources = Array.prototype.map.call(images, function(img) {
        return img.src;
    });
```

I've used the above selector `'.e1 img[src]'` to make sure that the returned `NodeList` only has images with `src` attributes.

JSFiddle Demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/u9Lkada3/1/

---

**Don't forget!** You need to run the script **after** the elements exist in the document. The easiest way to ensure this is to put your script at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @PieroG seems to work just fine in the fiddle. Your HTML must be different or you're running the JavaScript **before** the elements exist in the document.