# Using data-* to set placeholder of inner child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how I can use the `data-*` attribute of a parent div to set a placeholder in a child div.

I am modifying a form and am somewhat restricted in editing the code of the div itself so I need to use JavaScript to add the necessary attributes.

Some info:

- The parent and child divs do not have a unique ID or class which makes a straightforward approach like `getElementBy...().placeholder="blahblah";` not possible
- The format of the heirarchy and respective classes and IDs are shared globally across all fields in the form. They all have a parent div (class defines width of box), and 3 child divs within ("aaa - label", "bbb - editor", "ccc - validation")
- The parent div does have a `data-field` I can possibly make use of since the placeholder necessary depends on the type of input (DOB, SSN, etc.)

Is there a way I can get the `data-*` **name** and assign a placeholder to its child? I know you can grab the `data-*` attribute itself using `getAttribute('data-field');` but how to specify the name value attached to it?

How do I specifically target `data-field="SSN"` and then assign a placeholder to `class="bbb"` in the child div contained within?

Comment: Is this what you look for?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are describing in your last question?

`$('*[data-field="SSN"]').children().find('.bbb');`

"Find any node with data-field equal to SSN, then for its children, find a node classed bbb" ?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

So the markup would look like this then?

```
<div data-field="SSN">
    <label for="text" class="aaa">label</label>
    <input type="text" class="bbb">
    <span class="ccc">validation</span>
</div>
```

If so then you may want to use this :

```
$('div[data-field="SSN"]').children('.bbb').prop('placeholder', 'some_text_here');
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hn5ynffq/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery by any chance

Comment: oh i forgot... in the comments  at line 3: it should be 'container[0]' !