# How to remove all the attribute and values associated in tags in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Hi i wanted to remove all the attribute values and styles associated with a `tag` in `html`

**Input:**

```
<div id="content">
   <span id="span" data-span="a" aria-describedby="span">span</span>
   <p class="a b c" style="color:black;">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**my expected output:**

```
<div id="content">
   <span>span</span>
   <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**what i have tried:**

```js
$(function(){
  var content = $('#content').html();
  $(content).removeAttr("style");
  $(content).html().replace(/<~="">/, "");
  console.log(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
       <span id="span" data-span="a" aria-        describedby="span">span</span>
       <p class="a b c" style="color:black;">paragraph</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would write a parser, which takes the original structure and recreats simply its element structure. Done.

Comment: what do you mean values .. attributes i get , but what  are values ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion,  what I'm trying to do is,  the html structure I have represented first in that all the `tag` related `styles`,  `data-attributes` etc has to be removed.    In one word I want plain tag like this `<p></p>`

Comment: but your output contains id on div and not on span , and also text inside tags should still be there ?

Comment: @ashish Singh,  forget about outer div which contain id,  inside tag text I want with tag name only not any other properties

Comment: so you want to clean up everything inside `content` only, is that so ?

Comment: Yes it  such I want

Comment: Possible duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Element.getAttributeNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames) to get array of all names and iterate that to remove them

```js
$('#content *').each(function(_, el) { 
  el.getAttributeNames().forEach(el.removeAttribute.bind(el));
});

console.log($('#content')[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <span id="span" data-span="a" aria-describedby="span">span</span>
  <p class="a b c" style="color:black;">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Note polyfill required for some browsers

Comment: can it be done with regex? if yes please show me that

Comment: Don't use regex on html. If it is just a string and not in dom put it into a temporary element use above on it there

Comment: thank you very much for great solution, can you please explain this line `forEach(el.removeAttribute.bind(el));`

Comment: Just a shorter way to write `forEach(function(name){el.removeAttribute(name)})`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Choose [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to get children and remove all attributes with [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) with each element

```js
$(function() {
    var content = $('#content');
    $(content).removeAttr("style");
    $(content).children().each(function() {
        var attrs = Array.from(this.attributes);
        for(var attr of attrs){
            $(this).removeAttr(attr.name);
        }
    });
    console.log(content.html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
   <span id="span" data-span="a" aria-describedby="span">span</span>
   <p class="a b c" style="color:black;">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show me one regex solution, if possible

Comment: Click `run code snippet`, my result same your expected output.

Comment: But you said need a regex solution, I don't understand it

Comment: no as per my current solution, i'm using regex in other solution that's why i was curious to see that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove multiple attributes at onece:

```js
const $content = $('#content');

$content.find('*').each((i, elem) => {
  const attrs = [...elem.attributes].map(attr => attr.name).join(' ');
  $(elem).removeAttr(attrs);
});


console.log($content.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <span id="span" data-span="a" aria-describedby="span">span</span>
  <p class="a b c" style="color:black;">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show me one regex solution, if possible

Answer (score 0):

this snippet can help you

```
$(main);

function main() {

  var a = $('#content *');
  a.toArray().forEach(x => {
    var attrs = attrNames(x);
    attrs.forEach(attr => x.removeAttribute(attr));

  })
}


function attrNames (el) {
  return [...el.attributes].map(x => x.name)
}
```

basically you can get attribute list using `attributes` property and then remove each one of them from the element

Comment: can you please show me one regex solution, if possible