# Select node by attribute value without name

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I need to get elements with an attribute value containing a string, without specifying the attribute name.

I tried `[**="word"]` and `[*="word"]` but it's not valid.
Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Do you wish to set apart **string-type** elements of an array?

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean, I have a set of node and subnodes, and some of them will have attributes whose value contains a word. I have a treatment to perform on these nodes (add a data-attribute).

Comment: I was about to add a comment, but the question was closed.  There is another post the might help you on SO besides the one mentioned above.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yeah I used that for something else but since I want to traverse the children nodes too it's not that convenient. I'll use it too if I want to search customely