# Get image alt using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, alt

I have

```
<img alt="text" src="source" />
```

I'd like to get this alt to one var in JavaScript. It'll be better if it won't be necessary to use jQuery.

Please for help :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048720/691711)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
document.getElementById('imgId').getAttribute('alt')
```

Answer (score 0):

can get any attribute by `.getAttribute`

i.e.

```js
imgAlt.getAttribute("alt")

imgAlt.getAttribute("title")
```

```js
const imgAlt = document.getElementById("myImg");

console.log(imgAlt.getAttribute("alt"));
```

```html
<img id="myImg" alt="text" src="source" />
```