# How to use data attribute name and value in HTML-slightly

Tags: javascript, html, aem

We have a requirement to get the attribute value and set it in the script file. So , How can we check the date-attribute-name(id, url, etc..) and set the value in the one trust script.
Please verify and let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify with an example

Answer (score 0):

you can use getAttribute & setAttribute methods

for example

```
document.getElementById('element').getAttribute('id')
document.getElementById('element').setAttribute('id', 'newId')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i need to check the attribute name and assign it only in HTML .Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @SrigaDevi you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5282801/10169261

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById('element').getAttribute('id')`. When the attribute not exists you will get a `null`.

So you can check later whether the attribute exists.

```
if (document.getElementById('element').getAttribute('id') !== null) {
   // continue
}
```