# Iterating over element attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, traversal

I know individual attributes can be retrieved with the `attr()` method, but I'm trying to iterate over **all** of the attributes for an element.  For context, I'm using jQuery on some XML...

```
<items>
  <item id="id123" name="Fizz" value="Buzz" type="xyz">
    <subitem name="foo">
    <subitem name="bar">
  </item>
  <item id="id456" name="Bizz" value="Bazz" type="abc">
    <subitem name="meh">
    <subitem name="hem">
  </item>
</items>
```

I am already able to iterate over the items with...

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  // Do something to each item here...
});
```

But I'd like to be able to get an array of attributes for each 'item' so I can then iterate over those...

e.g.

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  var attributes = $(this).attributes(); // returns an array of attributes?
  for (attribute in attributes) {
    // Do something with each attribute...
  }
});
```

I've done some searching here, in the jQuery documentation, and elsewhere via Google but have had no luck.  If nothing else, I may just be having trouble excluding results relating to the `attr()` method of the jQuery object.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705504/javascript-jquery-how-do-i-get-an-array-of-all-attributes-in-an-xml-element

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The best way is to use the node object directly by using its `attributes` property. The only difference in my solution below compared to others suggesting this method is that i would use `.each` again instead of a traditional js loop:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
     var name = attrib.name;
     var value = attrib.value;
     // do your magic :-)
  });
});
```

Comment: @prodigalson: Thanks for this approach to an indexed foreach!

Answer (score 12):

it seems you have to use plain old vanilla javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
    if (attrib.specified == true) {
        console.log(attrib.name + " = " + attrib.value);
    }
}
```

[How to iterate through all attributes in an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828311/how-to-iterate-through-all-attributes-in-an-html-element)

Comment: And theres nothing wrong with that. attr() is a convenience method.

Answer (score 4):

Could you get the DOM element from the jQuery wrapper using the get() function, and then iterate the DOM attributes?

```
var node = $(myStuff).get(0);
if (node.attributes.length) {

    for (var length = attrs.length, i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (attrs[i].specified) {

        }
    }
}
```

For some much more robust DOM attribute handling, [check this blog post](http://snipt.net/pdokas/iterating-over-dom-attributes/).

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  var attributes = $(this)[0].attributes;
  for (attribute in attributes) {
    // Do something with each attribute...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can just use the standard DOM Element attribute `attributes`, it will include *every* attribute (even those not explicitly set) in IE6. As an alternative, you can limit the number of attributes you set:

```
var use_attributes = ['id','name','value','type'];
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
  var $item = $(this);

  $.each( use_attributes, function(){
    if($item.attr( this )){
      // Act on the attribute here. 
      // `this` = attribute name
      // $item.attr( this ) = attribute value
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here because I think it may help others that arrive at this posting looking to parse an xml file as I was.

I was looking for a method of traversing an xml file with a very similar structure to theracoonbear's fle and storing the results in an array and came across this posting.

I looked at prodigitalson's code but I simply could not get this syntax to work - with firefox complaining that in the line:

```
 $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
```

that

> this.attributes

is not a defined function.  **I am quite sure that the error is entirely mine**. But I have spent several hours attempting to get this working and have failed

What worked for me was (where my tag name is session instead of item):-

```
$(xml_Data).find("session").each(function() {
    console.log("found session");
    $(this).children().each(function(){
     console.log("found child " + this.tagName);
     console.log("attributes" + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

I appreciate that this may not exactly answer the original question. However I hope that it may save other visitors to this post some time.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

created this generic function that allows to look-in attributes as well as innearHtml:

```
function findByAll(toLookFor, lookInText) { 
    return $('*').filter(function() { 
        return Array.prototype.some.call(this.attributes, function(attr) {
            return attr.value.indexOf(toLookFor) >= 0; 
        }) || (lookInText && $(this).text().indexOf(toLookFor) >= 0); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Pure JS** First, your input xml is not [valid](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/), but you can fix it by close subitem tags by `/`

```
let items = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml,"text/xml").querySelectorAll('item');

items .forEach( (item,i)=> Object.values(item.attributes).forEach(a => {
  // your code
  console.log(`Item ${i}. attr ${a.name} = ${a.value}`)
}));
```

```js
let xml=`<items>
  <item id="id123" name="Fizz" value="Buzz" type="xyz">
    <subitem name="foo" />
    <subitem name="bar" />
  </item>
  <item id="id456" name="Bizz" value="Bazz" type="abc">
    <subitem name="meh" />
    <subitem name="hem" />
  </item>
</items>`;

let items  = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml,"text/xml").querySelectorAll('item');

items .forEach( (item,i)=> Object.values(item.attributes).forEach(a => {
  // your code
  console.log(`Item ${i}. attr ${a.name} = ${a.value}`)
}));
```