# Change the tag name but keep all the attributes

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
<span id="anId" someOtherAttributes....>test</span>
```

which I want to change into:

```
<a id="anId" theSameOtherAttributes...>test</a>
```

I have two questions :

1. How can I change just the tag name?

   or
2. How can I copy all the attributes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: seems like that doesn't carry attributes over though

Answer (score 7):

Here's a non-elegant, but working solution:

```
// create a new <a> element
new_element = $("<a/>");
// iterate over every attribute of the #some_id span element
$.each($("#some_id").get(0).attributes, function(i, attrib) {
        // set each attribute to the specific value
        $(new_element).attr(attrib.name, attrib.value);

});
// carry over the html content
new_element.html($("#some_id").html());
// finally, swap the elements   
$("#some_id").replaceWith(new_element);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `outerHtml` propery of the `HTMLElement` you want to change.

In this way, it becomes very easy to change a `span` to an `a`nchor: we just need to replace `^<span` with `<a` and `</span>$` with `</a>`.
Using a regular expression to change just the first and the last occurrence of the opening and closing tag, we keep the attributes as they originally were.

The code is here:

```
var newElement = $('a-selector').get(0).outerHTML.replace(/^<span/, "<a").replace(/<\/span>$/, "</a>");
$('a-selector').replaceWith(newElement);
```

This example uses jQuery. Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterJack/kK7cC/) to see it working.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to achieve here? If it is just styling, then using CSS would be better. If you want something to become a clickable link (or a link to become non-clickable), then you can just remove the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to code it, but to head you in the right direction, lookup how to build a tag in jquery (something like http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Then loop through each tag with something like [Iterating over element attributes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224933/iterating-over-element-attributes-with-jquery), and add each attribute to the appended tag.

EDIT: fine, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/xUUn3/

Comment: When I used el.attributes, I have got 'undefined'. But I tried el.attr("class"), I have something. So Why el.attributes return undefined ?

Comment: Where is the el. coming from?  Inside the loop there are two variable specifically for the attribute name & value, just create the new tag with something like `$('#thetagidORsomething').append('<span>tag</span>').attr('id','tmp');`  Then inside the loop assign each attribute to the item with the id of `tmp`.  I added an example to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use to replace html tags in jquery:

```
// Iterate over each element and replace the tag while maintaining attributes
$('span#anId').each(function() {

  // Create a new element and assign it attributes from the current element
  var NewElement = $("<a />");
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
    $(NewElement).attr(attrib.name, attrib.value);
  });

  // Replace the current element with the new one and carry over the contents
  $(this).replaceWith(function () {
    return $(NewElement).append($(this).contents());
  });

});
```

The `each` function I use on the first line is somewhat unnecessary in this case, as we are only selecting a single item by id. I still prefer using `each` here, since would allow this same code to loop through all items with a specific class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with jQuery :

```
function replaceElementTag(targetSelector, newTagString) {
    $(targetSelector).each(function(){
        var newElem = $(newTagString, {html: $(this).html()});
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            newElem.attr(this.name, this.value);
        });
        $(this).replaceWith(newElem);
    });
}
```

And example usage :

```
replaceElementTag('img', '<amp-img></amp-img>');
```