# Replace tag and keep attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the tag name but keep all the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482847/change-the-tag-name-but-keep-all-the-attributes)

Is it possible to replace an `<a>` tag with a `<span>` tag and keep all of it's attributes?

I have this HTML, and when someone clicks on **Edit** I want to convert all edit links to span's

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit" data-id="123">Edit</a>
```

Once the user is done editing (by either pressing **Save** or **Cancel**) I then want to convert all the span tags back into links.

```
$(".edit").live("click", function(){
    $(".edit").addClass("inactive-link");
});
```

Comment: Easily? I do not think so. But why do you need that at all? Simplest here would be to change style of all edit links (so they look like inactive) and block event handlers execution.

Comment: @FAngel how would I disable it temporarily? see edits

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482847/change-the-tag-name-but-keep-all-the-attributes

Comment: Disable what? The click function? It's already disabled. You want to change the `cursor` so it appears as it's no longer a link on hover?

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem... so your actual question is how to disabled the user interaction on the link?

Comment: I used 2 answers, to fix my issue... How do I choose both?

Comment: @RyanNaddy Choose the one which was most helpful? And write which answer were also used in comments or in question body. You can select only one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FAngel indicates, style changes are much simpler in this case.  I'm going to go ahead and use event delegation instead of `.live` in my example because `.live` will be removed in later jQuery versions:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
   //add inactive class to *this* link
   $(this).addClass('inactive-link');

   //stop default link behavior, i.e. opening a new page
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Will this disable all edit links? because that is what I want.

Comment: @RyanNaddy yes, every `.edit` link that is clicked will call `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @ExplosionPills `e.preventDefault()` is useless in order to prevent onclick handler execution. While it is good as a replacement for `href="javascript:void(0);"`, it will not prevent execution of attached events.

Comment: @FAngel I may have misunderstood .. if he wants to prevent other attached handlers from firing he should use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 3):

This should suit your needs:

```js
function switchTag(e, toTag) {
    var outerHTML = e.outerHTML;
    outerHTML = outerHTML.replace(/^<([a-z])(.*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>$/ig, "<" + toTag + "$2>$3</" + toTag + ">");
    e.outerHTML = outerHTML;
};
```

Example of use:

```js
$(".edit").click(function() {
    switchTag(this, "span");
});
```

[Demo available](http://jsfiddle.net/8kKMS/) ;)

Comment: Thanks for using plain JS, this SHOULD be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".edit").live("click", function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass("inactive-link")) { //suppose $(this) will work instead of $(e.target), but do not remember for sure
         $(".edit").addClass("inactive-link");// after this is done - this function will not execute anymore for .edit elements because of previouse if statement
         //code to start editing
    }
});
```

Just check if clicked element has class inactive-link. And remove it after editing is done.

Basically, there is no "disable" feature for links. But you can unbind event handlers while in edit mode, or check if links has some class, like in my code above.

Also, please note that live is deprecated and you should better use `.on` (if you have some latest jQuery, v1.7 and higher). [Here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you can find how to replace `live` with `on`

Comment: Thanks, I used this as well, but I could only choose one.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replacement Tag
var replacementTag = 'span';

$('a').each(function() {
    var outer = this.outerHTML;

    // Replace opening tag
    var regex = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName, 'i');
    var newTag = outer.replace(regex, '<' + replacementTag);

    // Replace closing tag
    regex = new RegExp('</' + this.tagName, 'i');
    newTag = newTag.replace(regex, '</' + replacementTag);

    $(this).replaceWith(newTag);
});
```

Link http://jsfiddle.net/tTAJM/19/

Answer (score 0):

I would use two containers : `links` and `edit-links`

When edit button is pressed, I would populate div `edit-links` with all the `<a>` tags from container links converted to `<span>`

When save button is pressed, I would re-create all the `<a>` tags in the `links` container.

```
$('#myButtonEdit').click(function(){        
    $('#links').hide();
    $('#edit-links').empty();

    //loop on all <a> tags to create <span> in edit-links div
    $('a').each(function(){
        $('#edit-links').append('<span id="'+this.id+'" class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'">'+$(this).attr('href')+'</span>');
    });
});

$('#myButtonSave').click(function(){

    $('#edit-links').hide();
    $('#links').empty();

    //loop on all <span> tags to create <a> in links container
    $('#edit-links span').each(function(){
        $('#links').append('<a id="'+this.id+'" class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'" href="'+$(this).html()+'">'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides I don't like the way you want to solve your problem, here is one possible solution:

```
function replaceElement(el, tagName) {
  var attrs = {
    text: el.innerHTML
  };
  $.each(el.attributes, function() {
    attrs[this.nodeName] = this.nodeValue;
  });
  $(el).replaceWith($("<" + tagName + " />", attrs));
}

$("a.edit").on("click", function() {
  replaceElement(this, "span");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rxzdK/

Here new element will contain all attributes from the replaced element. However you should consider that `<span>` shouldn't have `src` attribute according to the standards.