# Process data-attributes: how to seralize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create and HTML chart with a jquery plugin and I'm using HTML5 data attributes to pass data from my rails app to jquery function.

My html, after the ruby hash conversion, is something like this:

```
<div class="chart" data-contents-01="0" data-contents-02="1" data-contents-03="3" data-contents-04="0" data-contents-05="0" data-contents-06="0" data-contents-07="0" data-contents-08="0" data-contents-09="0" data-contents-10="0" data-contents-11="0" data-contents-12="0" data-contents-13="0" data-contents-14="0" data-contents-15="0" data-contents-16="0" data-contents-17="0" data-contents-18="0" data-contents-19="0" data-contents-20="0" data-contents-21="0" data-contents-22="0" data-contents-23="2" data-contents-24="1" data-contents-25="4" data-contents-26="0" data-contents-27="0" data-contents-28="0" data-contents-29="2" data-contents-30="2" data-contents-31="0" id="chart_2" style="padding: 0px; position: relative;">
```

I have a lot if `data-contents-xx` and I must convert this data to an array of array.

My function take data as:

```
 var contents = [
                    [x, y],
                    [x,y]
                ];
```

so I must process my data attributes to have an array of array, where each sub-array is a couple of data-contents-x

How can i serialize my data attribute?

Comment: This answer might put you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224933/iterating-over-element-attributes-with-jquery

Comment: I try but I cant figure how to iterate between data-contents-xx

With ruby for me is easy, with jquery no!

Is there something like a map method to build an array of array?

Comment: Do you need to serialize to separate data-* attributes? Both Rails and jQuery can handle a single data attribute with a json encoded array of values.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery method .data() will pull all data objects into an array of key: value pairs. With your element names:

```
$('.chart').data();
```

For example, given:

```
<div class="chart" data-foo="1" data-bar="2"></div>
```

Use:

```
var data = $('.chart').data();

for(var i in data){
    console.log("data attribute - " + i + ":" + data[i]);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WVfSg/260/

When playing with your code in the fiddle, it doesn't work. However, when I get rid of the second hyphen, it works as expected.

Comment: I try but is not working.

`$('.chart').data();` return me

`Object {plot: Plot, resizeSpecialEvent: Object}`

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted the code and added a link to the fiddle. Your div configuration isn't working it looks like because of the second hyphen in your data names.